# php list each key and value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm a beginner in php, so apologize if you will find the question a little weird.

i'm trying to check 2 variables that i POST and store in a session array. The 2 variables are the size and the color of an item in a shopping cart.

How can I check if theses 2 variables are already existing in my session array. If it's the case i just want to increment them quantity. In fact, i think i'm just missing to write my if statement for check this case. Here's the code:

```
   if (isset($_POST['ID']) && isset($_POST['SIZE']) && isset($_POST['COLOR'])) {

    $product = $_POST['ID'];
    $size = $_POST['SIZE'];
    $color = $_POST['COLOR'];

  $Found = false;
  $i = 0;
  // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
  if (!isset($_SESSION["myArray"]) || count($_SESSION["myArray"]) < 1) {
      // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["myArray"] = array(0 => array("productID" => $product, "quantity" => 1, "size"=> $size, "color" => $color));
  } else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["myArray"] as $each_item) {
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item))
          {
            if (($key == "productID" && $value == $product))//<- IT'S PROBABLY WHERE I SHOULD CHECK THEM BUT HOW????
            {
              // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
              array_splice($_SESSION["myArray"], $i-1, 1, array(array("productID" => $product, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1, "size"=> $size, "color" => $color)));
              $wasFound = true;
            } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
       if ($Found == false) {
         array_push($_SESSION["myArray"], array("productID" => $product, "quantity" => 1, "size"=> $size, "color" => $color));
       }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your helps guys.

Comment: "If these 2 variables are existing in my session array..." `in_array($_POST['var'], $_SESSION)` maybe can give you some help.

Comment: Mr Zerquix, Thanks you really ;)  it's working easily and perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to list key and value of an array ?

```
 foreach ($_SESSION["myArray"] as $key=>$each_item) {
```

> How can I check if theses 2 variables are already existing in my
>   session array.

```
if(array_key_exist('color',$_SESSION["myArray"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something easier (myArray seems a bad name, in my opinion):

```
$product_id = $_POST['ID']; //You should sanitize this input!
if(array_key_exist($product_id,$_SESSION["myCart"])) {
    $_SESSION["myCart"][$product_id]['quantity']++;
} else {
    $size = $_POST['SIZE']; //Sanitize this input as well
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $_SESSION["myCart"][$product_id] = array(
        'size' => $size,
        'color' => $color,
        'quantity' => 1,
    );
}
```

Hope it helps :)